# Send Salam to all Mu'min in My dua?

Tags: practical-islam, dua

I feel like sending Salam to all Mu'mins in my dua after prayer, otherwise every dua becomes too self-centred.

Is there any dua particularly for this purpose?

Comment: There are plenty mentioned in Quran and Sunna, but AFAIK no (special) one have been reported to be said/recited after prayer

Answer (score 1):

A good dua for mu'min slaves can be a part of Tashahhud.

**Assalamu 'ala 'ibadillaahis salehin.**

**السّلام علی عباد اللّه الصلحین**

**Peace on the righteous slaves of Allah**